# Javascript/Prototype Effect Parallel not working in IE10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, slider, prototypejs, internet-explorer-10

I am having trouble with my JS in IE10 (IE7-9 works "fine")

I have a slider with a fade/appear transition effect. When sliding to the next picture, the current one is faded out, while the next one is faded in. Problem is, that IE10 doesn't do the effect, it only hides the current one and shows the next one (but the delay between clicking the Next button and the showing of the next picture equals the duration of the effect on other browsers, so it does do something..)

There are no console or js errors..

This is my code:

```
var effects = new Array();

effects.push(new Effect.Fade(this.previous, {
    sync: true
}));

effects.push(new Effect.Appear(this.current, {
    sync: true
}));

this.scrolling = new Effect.Parallel(effects, {
    duration: this.options.duration,
    afterFinish: (function() {
        if (this.controls) {
            this.activateControls();
        }
        if (this.options.afterMove && (typeof this.options.afterMove == 'function')) {
            this.options.afterMove();
        }
    }).bind(this)
});
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

i don't think this effect supports i.e 10 as you can see in documentation http://madrobby.github.io/scriptaculous/effect-parallel/
demo here is also not showing effect in i.e 10.