# Fade on scroll effect don't work in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I  created a fade on scroll effect, for a GitHub contribution. but it doesn't work in Internet Explorer.

In CodePen, the code works in Internet Explorer, but, in plain HTML it doesn't work in Internet Explorer 11

[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/FelipeMartinin/pen/shEme)

[HTML PAGE](https://github.com/FelipeMartinin/fadeonscroll)

Comment: After a quick look at your CodePen link, I would look into CSS3 Transitions. At your own risk under IE10 but polyfills are relatively easy to find. A good starting point would be [this quick tutorial](http://bavotasan.com/2011/a-simple-fade-with-css3/).

Comment: I understand. But, why i not understand is what the html page version don't work in IE, but the code pen version works. Can you see that and give you opinion?

Comment: I think [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18351663/2748327) might help you; it might not be _exactly_ what you're looking for, but it might point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I saw in the code you used `-webkit-.....`. That is webkit only (i.e. Chrome and Safari).